# Try and except clauses for appending elements in lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that can have up to three elements, and I want to append them to three list, because I get this list from another element within a loop. My final goal is to have a dataframe with the data of all elements. I have coded this:

```
affected_projects_1 = []
affected_projects_2 = []
affected_projects_3 = []

for issue in project:
    affected_projects = issue.affected_projects
    try:
        affected_projects_1.append(affected_projects[0])
    except IndexError:
        affected_projects_1.append('')
    except:
        raise Exception
    try:
        affected_projects_2.append(affected_projects[1])
    except IndexError:
        affected_projects_2.append('')
    except:
        raise Exception
    try:
         affected_projects_3.append(affected_projects[2])
    except IndexError:
        affected_projects_3.append('')
    except:
        raise Exception

 df = pd.DataFrame(zip(affected_projects_1, affected_projects_2, affected_projects_3))
```

This piece of code seems pretty verbose and almost repetitive (the only thing that changes is the number). How could I make it more compact? Is that even possible without losing readability or using antipatterns (i.e using globals variables). Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _I want to append them to three list, because I get this list from another element within a loop_?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I am getting info from Redmine (project management tool), which consist in a series of issues (tickets, tasks, whatever you want to call them) that contains info like name, author(s), hours spent etc. I am doing a loop for all the issues, and for each info field, I create before the loop an empty list, and in each iteration I append the value of the field to the list, so that at the end I can create a dataframe zipping the lists. So for instance: authors_list = []; for issue in issues: authors_list.append(issue.author).

Answer (score 2):

`except: raise Exception` is awful.

1. It converts all errors to `Exception`.

   - This means errors that have nothing to do with `Exception` like `BaseException` and `KeyboardInterupt` are now something they semantically are not.
   - This also means if you have a `KeyError` then it's magically the same as any other error.
2. It doesn't even raise an exception instance, `Exception()`.
3. There's no need for it, just remove it from your code.

---

If you weren't appending to different lists then we could see that all we need is a basic for loop.

```
for proj in issue.affected_projects[:3]:
    affected.append(proj)
```

Since you have to append to other lists you can zip over them.

```
for affected, proj in zip(affected_projects, issue.affected_projects):
    affected.append(proj)
```

Since you need to default to `''` you can just extend `issue.affected_projects` to these values.

```
affected_projects = [[], [], []]
for issue in project:
    for affected, proj in zip(
        affected_projects,
        issue.affected_projects + 3*['']
    ):
        affected.append(proj)
```

We can remove the need for `affected.append` by moving the zip up one loop.

```
affected_projects = zip(*(
    (issue.affected_projects + 3*[''])[:3]
    for issue in project
))
pd.DataFrame(zip(*affected_projects))
```

Since you are `zip`ing `affected_projects` and you're zipping `issue.affected_projects` you don't really need to `zip` at all.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    (issue.affected_projects + 3*[''])[:3]
    for issue in project
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I remove except Exception, what happens when there is an error but it is not IndexError?

Comment: @JavierLópezTomás It propagates up as if there were no `try`.